# ANOVA or Multiple t-tests for comparing multiple organs in two mice groups

Tags: anova, t-test, experiment-design, two-way

I am comparing two mice groups (1 experimental and 1 control) but I obtain data from 4 different organs of these mice. When I order my data (using GraphPad Prism) I use a grouped table and graph to visualize it. After that I hit the Analyze button and use the default analysis **Two-way anova** to look for significance between my two groups in the different organs. However I also have the option to compare my groups using **Multiple t-tests** but I don't know if I would get more or less accurate results if I use this analysis.

Which statistical analysis (ANOVA or Multiple t-tests) is better for this experimental design? Why?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to consider an analysis suited for multivariate outcomes - such as a MANOVA or a mixed-effects/multi-level model.